How can I use Provider to provide both initial values and save changed values in TextFields?
I have an app with a simple data model
    Note(
      String title,
      String content
    )

The part of the UI I'm asking about is basically a Row with a ListView displaying note titles next to a Column with TextFields for a selected note's title and content. It's the classic master/detail view.
    Row (
      children: [
        ListView(),
        Column(
          children: [
            TextField(),
            TextField(),
            ]
        ),
      ],
    )

Both TextFields have associated TextEditingControllers.
I'm managing state with Provider.
I want to be able to do two things:

When user taps a ListView item, corresponding note is displayed in TextFields
When user changes text in TextFields, Provider updates and saves list of Notes (the Provider update method I wrote works fine, it's not the issue).

Right now I do #2 via the TextField's onChanged event, e.g.,
    onChanged: (value) {
      context.read<Data>().update(content: value);
  },

For #1, tapping the ListView tells Provider which Note (in a list of Notes) was selected
    onTap: () {
       context.read<Data>().selectedIndex(index);
    },

And the selected item's values are then assigned to controller.text properties during the Column widget's build method
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Note? selectedNote = context.read<Data>().selectedNote;
    noteTitleController.text = selectedNote.title;
    noteTextController.text = selectedNote.content;

I also tried assigning values by overriding the didChangeDependencies() method, but all the ways I've tried to do #1 involve setting TextEditingController.text values during a widget build process. As I learned a few days ago, that causes problems. As shown above, when a user triggers the TextField onChange event,

the Provider updates and
notifies its listeners,
the Column widget rebuilds,
the TextFields rebuild, and
their cursors jump to the beginning of the text. That's undesirable :-)

How can I use Provider to provide both initial values and save changed values in TextFields?

set listen true it will  continuously listen to your provider just like a web socket or stream.
context.read<Data>().update(content: value, listen:true)// or change it into this
Data.of<Data>(context,listen:true);

Moreover you create String type variables in provider assign them some initial value if possible. after that when page builds get the value of those variables and assign them to your text editing controllers. Hopefully it will fix It was little hard to understand the question for me if you need any help I'm free today you can ask me by doing comment.

Thanks for responding. I added some more information to the original post.
